# How to bulk update tables with large data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to update column in one table with the content from column in another table in oracle. Since these tables has around 4 million records each, i am facing difficulty doing the update.

**Table A Structure(Staging Table)**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
L1      P1      PC1     D1
L2      P2      PC2     D1
L3      P3      PC3     D2
L4      P3      PC3     D3
```

**Table B Structure**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
E1      P1      F1
E2      P1      F2
E3      P2      F3
E4      P3      F4
E5      P4      F5
```

I need to update **Col3** in **table B** with value from **Col4** from **table A** when there is match for **Col2** in **table A and B**.

I tried with merge command but since these 2 tables has millions of records, we are getting space issues on temp table.

Merge command that i used was

```
merge into b
using
(select col2,col4 from a) c
on c.col2=b.col2
when matched then update set b.col3=c.col4;
```

Is there better approach to handle this bulk update?

Comment: You have duplicate values for `Col2` in both tables, so the question is incomplete.  This duplicates are probably causing the space issue.  And, you should show your `merge` code in the question.

Comment: What value should `TableB.Col3` be set to when `TableB.Col2` is `'P3'`?  According to your description and `Table1` having two matching rows, it should be ***both*** `'D2'` and `'D3'`...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the merge query that i used.

Comment: Why don't you ask your  DBA / admin user to increase temp tablespace?

Comment: Did you try using collections, bulk update using FORALL ? We use this approach processing approximately 50k records in each loop.

Comment: Do the tables have indexes so you can efficiently locate a row given the `Col2` value? Does at least table `b` have such an index?

Answer (score 0):

For 4 million rows, I would check if a short downtime is possible and try

```
RENAME b TO b_old;

CREATE TABLE b AS 
SELECT col1, col2, coalesce(a.col4, b_old.col3) as col3
  FROM b_old 
  LEFT JOIN a ON a.col2 = b_old.col2;

Recreate indexes, constraints, comments etc on b

DROP TABLE b_old;
```

If that's still too slow, I'd look into partitioning both tables an run the recreate as in parallel.